# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory in Spring tool suite

Tags: java, maven, slf4j, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Spring tool suite(Version: 3.7.1.RELEASE) and try to create simple spring maven project.I have added dependencies in pom.xml. when I'm using my Desktop it is working fine and when I'm trying to use the same thing in my Laptop it's gave me above error. I've also tried downloading the jar files manually but no luck. Can anyone help me? my pom.xml attached bellow.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocatioenter code heren="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
      <artifactId>Springtesting</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
    <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    <!-- Test -->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Test Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: In your laptop did you try the following: 1) If the REPO is pointed or referenced correctly  2) If you tried with jars, they need to be in the classpath. I would recommend cleaning and then again building.

Comment: Could you please guide me  to  referenced the REPO correctly ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "use the same thing"? It might have something to do with the settings.xml.

Comment: That's strange. As far as I see, you configured the dependencies for logback and slf4j correctly (and with the correct scopes). Are you building a jar or war file? In a jar you would have to include the dependencies manually, see here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html

Comment: @hotzst by same thing I meant the same version,same code and same dependencies.

Comment: But do you mean executing the maven build, and if yes with witch parameters? Or do you mean running the application using the artefact that maven created?

Comment: running the application as a java application the same way that I've done in my desktop

Comment: Sometimes deleting the local maven repo cache (~/.m2/repository) helps with Maven issues. Not sure if this solves your issue, but I would at least give it a try. Afterwards, start STS and do an "update project" to trigger the Maven tooling to download the artifacts again. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgrade java from 1.7 to 1.8 and gave the jre 1.8 as run time environment in STS. This solved my problem.